# How to read trace file(timeline) in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, timeline

The timeline trace file is introduced here:
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.1/performance/xla/jit

It seems useful for performance analyzing. But there is something I can't understand.

1, What does "pid" stand for while there are:

```
    /device:GPU:0/stream:35 Compute (pid 3)
    /device:GPU:0/stream:all Compute (pid 9)
    /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 Compute (pid 5)
```

2, A same OP can appear in different pids with absolutely different timestamp. What does that mean?

Can anybody help me? Or is there any document about this? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. 'pid' stands for process identifier.  According to a comment from a developer [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1824#issuecomment-244251867), "All of the numeric 'PID's and 'TID's in the UI should be ignored- they were just invented to get CTV [Chrome Trace Visualizer] to lay out the trace better but there's no way to stop the GUI displaying them!"
2. This probably means that the OP is running multiple times.